# Caching all remote notifications - iOS

Tags: ios, swift, push-notification, apple-push-notifications

Is there any way where I can cache all my incoming remote notifications?

As per my understanding, UNUserNotificationCenterDelegate provides two delegate methods: 'didReceive' & 'willPresent'

With the above delegate methods I can cache remote notifications

- When app is in foreground
- When app is in background/terminated state and notification is selected

But, I can not cache remote notification

- When app is in terminated state and app is opened by selecting app icon and not notification

So what can be done to achieve same? I am wondering if it is even possible.

I tried setting content-available as 1 with background fetch enabled. But this doesn't execute logic written in 'didReceiveRemoteNotification' block. 
I've verified this by keeping counter in UserDefaults. Wrote logic which increments counter from UserDefaults.
But counter doesn't seem to be incrementing in the case I mentioned above.

Comment: Have you tried to use the getDeliveredNotificationsWithCompletionHandler: method of the shared UNUserNotificationCenter object to get a list of notifications still being displayed in Notification Center, just after the app is launched?

Comment: @Woodstock didn't know something like this even existed! Just tried getDeliveredNotifications and it returns all the notifications from notifications tray. Thanks! ^^

Comment: no problem, added as answer, feel free to accept!

Comment: Add Notification service extention to your project. In that when a notification is received, you will get a callback in didReceiveNotificationRequest method. There you can store the notification in userdefaults. If you want to access those notifications into your app, you can use "App groups" and get all the notifications, irrespective of the state of the app.

Answer (score 0):

Use the `getDeliveredNotificationsWithCompletionHandler`: method of the shared `UNUserNotificationCenter` object to get a list of notifications still being displayed in Notification Center, just after the app is launched!

Comment: Hey Woodstock. I have a question..
So if I receive a notification when app is in terminated state and just simply clear it, I will be missing on that notification right?
Is there any way I can cache that as well?